# what is the best way to query?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, query-optimization, has-many, belongs-to

i am having two models `employee` and `in_outs`. the association between these are `employee` `has many` `in_outs` and `in_out` `belongs to` `employee`.i want to display the `attendance` of all the `employees`. For this my `current logic` is this.

logic in controller action:

```
def view_all_employee_attendance
  employees = Employee.all
  @all_employess_punch_in_outs = []
  employees.each do |employee|
    @all_employess_punch_in_outs << employee.in_outs.where('date >= ? and date <= ?', Date.today.at_beginning_of_month, Date.today)
  end
end
```

and in view :

```
      <tbody>
        <% @all_employess_punch_in_outs.each do |punch_record| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= punch_record.employee.name %></td>
            <td><%= punch_record.check_in %></td>   
            <td><%= punch_record.check_out %></td>   
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
```

in this case in my `view` again `queries` are executing. how to make this query `optimise` in `view` and in `action` by using `eagerloading`?

Comment: Your question has some code formatting issues.

Answer (score 1):

change you query line to this. This will eager load all your `in_outs` with the where clause so that you just run one query.This will make it so your view is optimized as well in won't have to run `N+1` queries in each time each time you request an `in_out`

```
employees = Employee.joins(:in_outs).all.where('in_outs.date >= ? and in_outs.date <= ?', Date.today.at_beginning_of_month, Date.today).preload(:in_outs)
```

Comment: The date is referring to the `in_outs` model so you should prefix date with `in_outs.date >= ?`

Comment: getting an error : ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid at /attendance/view_attendance
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'in_outs.date' in 'where clause': SELECT `employees`.* FROM `employees`  WHERE (in_outs.date >= '2016-10-01' and in_outs.date <= '2016-10-24')

Comment: i used this query : @all_employess_punch_in_outs = Employee.all.includes(:in_outs).where('date >= ? and date <= ?', Date.today.at_beginning_of_month, Date.today) ; still i am getting the same error

Comment: is there a `date` column on the in_out model, or is there a `created_at`?

Comment: its there. see this query : 2.2.2 :066 >   InOut.where('date >= ? and date <= ?', Date.today.at_beginning_of_month, Date.today)
  InOut Load (19.9ms)  SELECT `in_outs`.* FROM `in_outs`  WHERE (date >= '2016-10-01' and date <= '2016-10-24')
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<InOut id: 36444, employee_id: 1, shift_id: 20, shift_name: "10 to 7 30", check_in: "2016-10-02 05:00:00", check_out: "2016-10-19 18:38:00", date: "2016-10-01", status: "Absent", duration: "10 : 22", late: nil, early:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126536/discussion-between-john-and-c-dot-strifevii).

Answer (score 1):

Your query is being called again due to the following line in your view:
`punch_record.employee.name`.

In order to eager load `employee` you'll need to modify your query to be like so:

```
def view_all_employee_attendence
  @employee_in_outs = Employee.all.includes(:in_outs).where('in_outs.date >= ? and in_outs.date <= ?', Date.today.at_beginning_of_month, Date.today)
end
```

`includes` [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes).

Comment: Think yo have a typo here `include` should be `includes`

Comment: Thanks @CdotStrifeVII I've made the change!

Comment: might be a silly question but why use `all`? Won't `where(...).includes(:in_outs)` have the same effect?

Comment: i used this query => @all_employess_punch_in_outs = Employee.joins(:in_outs).all.where('in_outs.date >= ? and in_outs.date <= ?', Date.today.at_beginning_of_month, Date.today).preload(:in_outs) ; this is also not working.

Comment: That's not the query I suggested here @John